# Is there a way to recover contacts and T Memo from touch broken galaxy core

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, data-recovery, touch, samsung-galaxy-core

I have a samsung galaxy core and now the touch is broken. Since I have a new Redmi Y1, the damage of phone is not a big deal but the thing that matters is I am in need of copying all contacts and T Memo from the galaxy core to either laptop or Y1.

#### More Info

Only touch and the two touch-keys (back key and menu key) is not working.

Display, Speaker, Other keys etc. are working fine.

The handset is slightly wet on a rain yesterday.

It detects USB connection.

No pattern or pin is set. Only swipe lock is there.

I can access files from laptop because the default usb connection is media.

#### My Tries

I tried to use Dr.Fone's feature of recovering data from touch broken device. But My Device is not listed.

I googled for a way of doing this via CMD in fastboot mode but can't find any.

Is there any way I can copy the contacts from mobile to laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [OTG](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&client=ms-android-att-us&biw=360&bih=270&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Y00jWuLNIY_F_Qaox4HQBQ&q=%20otg%20wire&oq=%20otg%20wire&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3..0i67k1j0l4.16470.16470.0.17280.1.1.0.0.0.0.247.247.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-img..0.1.247....0.SsJgHl-0Pfs) cable to connect a mouse to the phone that will give you full access to the device.

You will then be able to go into contacts>settings>contact settings>export contacts, and select your desired method. I would suggest you export the contacts to an sd card, put it in into your new phone, and import them.

You should be able to do the same thing for your memos. Export them to an ad card, or save them to a cloud.

Comment: I already thought about it but Galaxy Core is an old model and won't support OTG